# How to automate click link in table cell by column name and row index using selenium (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want a generic approach to perform click link in table cell by providing **column name** and **row index**.

There may be multiple type of HTML table structure, but I need generic function which perform action in every table which looks like a generic HTML table.

For eg. following some generic tables are define :-

1- **first table structure**

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>column1</th><th>column2</th><th>column3</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="">Link1</a></td><td><a href="">Link2</a></td><td><a href="">Link2</a></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

2- **second table structure**

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>column1</td><th>column2</th><td>column3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="">Link1</a></td><th><a href="">Link2</a></th><td><a href="">Link2</a></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

3- **third table structure**

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>column1</td><td>column2</td><td>column3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="">Link1</a></td><td><a href="">Link2</a></td><td><a href="">Link2</a></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Here If I provide two parameter for eg.

```
String columnName = "column2", int rowIndex = 1;
```

then My generic function perform click link `Link2` in table cell at 2,1 in all tables.

I can find the table using `WebDriver` as follows :-

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
 WebElement tableElment = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table")));
```

But I do not know how to make a generic function to process this table as I want.

Please help me to create a generic function in `Java` to achieve this task.

Using `JavascriptExecutor` in `WebDriver` is also acceptable..

`Pseudo code` or `Algorithm` to achieve this is also acceptable..

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: I don't think this is possible for your table structures.  The provide too little information to provide a generic locator strategy.

Comment: @Mobrockers what does extra information you want????

Comment: Your tables do not provide enough information in general. If for example your table columns would have the header name as an attribute, I could create an xpath for you. But right now I do not think it is possible.

Comment: I know very well how to create xpath.. and i can also perform click on cell by using locator.. but here is my need a generic function which will automate action user perspective..

Comment: How can you say that it is not possible????

Comment: In general HTML tables have id, row and columns have classes to which they below something like this  - <table cellspacing="0" id="listingtable"> or for a row - <tr class="listrow"> and for columns like - <th class="listheader" align="left" scope="col"> I suppose this what @Mobrockers means to say....

Comment: Perhaps you could get all header columns and loop through them until you find the one matching your header name, and use the index where you find the matching element to create the xpath to find the right column.

Yes I suppose that would work. Would be better to create better tables though, in my opinion.

Comment: @PunkaajChavaan does HTML table not work without id,class????

Comment: @Mobrockers now you are going to right way....

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Offcourse they will work but these attributes are normally present in production quality HTML pages having tables...

Comment: @PunkaajChavaan you are right.. but here, I do not need to play with id,class etc to perform action.. so that's why I have provided only normal table for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the index of the column matching the targeted header and then return the link in the targeted row/column.
I would use a piece of JavaScript for this task:

```java
static WebElement getTableLink(WebElement table, String column, int row) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)((RemoteWebElement)table).getWrappedDriver();

    WebElement link = (WebElement)js.executeScript(
        "var rows = arguments[0].rows, header = arguments[1], iRow = arguments[2];      " +
        "var iCol = [].findIndex.call(rows[0].cells, (td) => td.textContent == header); " +
        "return rows[iRow].cells[iCol].querySelector('a');                              " ,
        table, column, row);

    return link;
}
```

Usage:

```java
// get the table
WebElement tableElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table")));

// click the link in column "column2", row 1
getTableLink(tableElement, "column2", 1).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @Florent... great answer..it works...:)... can you tell me how is it achieve without using javascript???

Comment: You could find the column index by iterating all the headers with `tableElement.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[0]/td"))` and `element.getText()`. Though it will be much more expressive compared to a single JavaScript call.

Comment: Yeah I know it much more expressive than JS...but here is my need...and By.xpath("//tr[0]/td") I can't find all columns because here are in some table "th" tag use for column header...

Comment: I'm just asking you can be possible in this scenario that I could automate without using JS or not???

Comment: Yes it's possible. First get the index from the list returned by `By.xpath(".//tr[0]/th")` or `By.xpath(".//tr[0]/td")`, and then get the cell with `By.xpath(".//tr[" + iRow +  "]/td[" +  iCol + "]")`.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with both using JS and without JS to clearly understand to me and other??

Comment: You need to understand that SO is not coding service. You are a software engineer, so it should be piece of cake for you to translate it to pure Java.

Comment: Yes you are right...after your suggestion I have completed my task...I'm not forcing you to write coding here..I'm just requesting you to write if you can for better understanding to other beacuase it's your answer...any way no problem.. and thanks..:)