# How to get the last row number of table which is dynamically updating?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

How we can get the Table(in a webpage) row using the value it contain.

Suppose a table of 3*3. In that cell(2,3) cell text is "Test". So how to find the row number = 2 using the the cell text "Test".

Selenium-2.53.1
Java-8

This is the xpath

> //table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/**tr[1]/td[1]**/div/a/font

in which bolded tr (here tr[1]) is the row I want to change dynamically & the text is inside the bolded td (here td[1])

My html code is :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="fm" method="post">
 <table>
    <!-- --Some data--- -->
 </table> 

  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" >
  <tr valign="top" > 
  <td width="200" height="100%" rowspan="3"  align="center" > 
        <p></p>
        <table width="89%" height="270" border="0">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <!-- --Some data--- -->
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr> 
       <td><table width="100%" height="71" border="0" align="right">
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
       </table></td>
    </tr>

    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <!-- --Some data--- -->
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    </table>
    <p></p>
  </td>  
  <td width="622" height="30" colspan="3" align="left" valign="top">
    <table width="100%" height="40" align="center">
          <tr><!-- --Some data--- --></tr>
    </table>
        <table width="476" height="110" align="center">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>  
    <!-- --Some data--- -->
    <tr></tr>     
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr> 
       <td height="22" colspan="3">
          <div align="left"> 
        <table width="469" border="1">
                  <tr bgcolor="#006291"> 
                     <td width="81" bgcolor="#006291"><div align="center">SlNo.</div></td>
                     <td width="82" bgcolor="#006291"><div align="center">Code</div></td>
                     <td width="300" bgcolor="#006291"><div align="center">Name</div></td>
          </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div align="left" style="width:465px;Height:150px;"> 
        <table width="465" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1">
        <tr bordercolor="#006291" bgcolor='#FFEADF' >
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=1"><font color="#006291" size="3" >1</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=1"><font color="#006291" size="3" >01</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="300" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=1"><font color="#006291" size="3" >tvm1</font></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#006291" bgcolor='#F1F8FC' >
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=2"><font color="#006291" size="3" >2</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=2"><font color="#006291" size="3" >02</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="300" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=2"><font color="#006291" size="3" >tvm2</font></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#006291" bgcolor='#FFEADF' >
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=3"><font color="#006291" size="3" >3</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=3"><font color="#006291" size="3" >03</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="300" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=3"><font color="#006291" size="3" >tvm3</font></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#006291" bgcolor='#F1F8FC' >
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=4"><font color="#006291" size="3" >4</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=4"><font color="#006291" size="3" >04</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="300" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=4"><font color="#006291" size="3" >tvm4</font></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#006291" bgcolor='#FFEADF' >
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=66"><font color="#006291" size="3" >5</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="81" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=66"><font color="#006291" size="3" >10</font></a></div></td>
          <td width="300" height='5' valign="top"><div align="center"><a href="t.php?Tcode=66"><font color="#006291" size="3" >tvm5</font></a></div></td>
        </tr>                
        </table>
              </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share your table HTML for better understanding??

Comment: yeah..I have added

Comment: So here you want to search row number on the basis of text. Right??

Comment: yes..I want to click on the td (here td with href="t.php")  on the basis of text.

Comment: on the basis of text or get the index of last row of that table(which is updating i.e, row is adding to that table dynamically). So that I can click on the last row

Comment: Try this xpath then : `.//td[child::a/font[text() = 'your text hare']]` and let me know...:)

Comment: Got index of last row using this `int rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")).size();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried capturing the column data of all rows into a List(observe the xpath of 'rowList' below, no number given for the final 'tr' which gets the column data for all rows), and using foreach got the index of the row which contains required text.

Will have to change the value in 'expRowValue' to have it worked with different data.

```
public class Table {
WebDriver driver; 

By rowList = By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]");

  @Test
  public void f() {
  String expRowValue="$513";

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/dell/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

List<WebElement>rowsData =  driver.findElements(rowList);
int k=1;    
for (WebElement rowValue: rowsData) {
    if (rowValue.getText().equals(expRowValue)){
        System.out.println("ROw Index::" + k);
    }
k++;    
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"count(//table[@id='tableid']//td[.='Test']/parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr) + 1"

put in your own table identifier... depends on it being a simple table without rowspans and colspans.

Comment: Let me try...this is my xpath "//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a/font"    and I am using the code    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a/font")).click();

Comment: Also the there is no table id or class   <table width="465" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#006291" border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

Comment: Share your html page source for the relevant table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on `<td>` on the basis of text try below `xpath` :-

```
.//td[child::a/font[text() = 'your text hare']]
```

Or if you to click on `<a>` inside `<td>` on the basis of text try below `xpath` :-

```
.//td/a[child::font[text() = 'your text hare']]
```

Or it you want to [click on table cell using their row and column index follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561317/how-to-automate-click-link-in-table-cell-by-column-name-and-row-index-using-sele)

Comment: Thank you Saurabh.  I want to click on <a> inside <td>...this is not working..Now time to leave..I'll check it on monday

Comment: yes i tried these `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[child::a/font[text() = 'abc123']]")).click();   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/a[child::font[text() = 'ccc']]")).click();`

Comment: Why are you going to long route?? only use as : `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//​td/a[child::font‌​[text() = 'ccc']]")).click();` is enough

Comment: but thats not working for me. I put the same code `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td/a[child::font[text() = 'ccc']]")).click();`